# Handling new and old pages when link opens new tab with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a page that is laid out roughly like:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <div>Click Me</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div>Also Click Me</div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div>Clicking is Fun</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Each of those divs is clickable, and the site (via Javascript, not via links with `target=_blank`, etc.) does two things when you click on them:

1. **A new tab is opened with a new URL.**
   I want to grab the URL of this new tab, plus parse
   some information out of the HTML on that page.
2. **The tab with the button is also redirected to a
   different URL** (maybe 3-4 redirection before it settles
   on a final destination).
   I want to grab the URL of this tab ... and I don't
   know if I also need to "go back" to the original URL
   so I can continue looping through the rest of
   the items/buttons on that original page.

For example, the browser has a tab with `URL-A` open (with the above HTML).  If I click on the first button, the `URL-A` tab is changed to `URL-B`, and a new tab is opened with `URL-C`.

The code so far:

```js
let page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(originalURL);
await page.waitForSelector('ul li.item');

// find the items
let allItems = await page.$$eval('ul li.item', (items) => {

    // for each item
    items = items.map(async (el) => {

        // find the button and its text
        const button = el.querySelector('.button');
        const buttonText = button.textContext.trim();

        // click the button
        await button.click();

        /**
         * DO ALL THE THINGS HERE
         */

        return {
            buttonText,
            urlFromNewTab,
            someTextFromNewTab,
            urlFromOldTab,
        };

    });

    // the array of parsed data from all items on the original page
    return items;

});

console.log(allItems);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that any code I've tried after the `button.click()` doesn't work, so I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: We are too, without a site to run the code on.

Comment: You could use https://www.forbes.com/coupons/homedepot.com/ as an example site.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still pretty vague. What information do you want? Please state exactly what your goal is, like the literal text and links you want for a few of the items. Otherwise I'm making guesses as to what you're thinking and writing code that might not even help you, which isn't worth the time. It's also nice if you make an attempt at solving it yourself rather than just leaving a comment where you want someone else to do the whole task for you. Also, you can't really use `async` with map like that without `Promise.all`. You probably want a traditional `for` loop here.

Comment: The goal is to visit that URL, and click on the "Get Deal" buttons.  When you do that, a new tab open (with a URL like https://www.forbes.com/coupons/homedepot.com/#c139150), and also the current tab changes (to e.g. https://www.homedepot.com/...)

I want to access those two pages so that I can grab text from them. That part I can do with things like `$$eval` and `querySelector()`, etc..  It's just getting a "page" object I can access that I'm not sure how to do. I also need to process _every_ button on that initial page, so I assume I need to go back to it ... somehow. Thanks!